# Using the --quiet tag when extending Mercurial

Tags: python, mercurial, mercurial-extension

I'm writing a Mercurial extension in Python and need to call the "Pull" command using the [Mercurial API](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi), but I want to suppress its output using the --quiet flag.

In Hg terms, I want to execute the following code, but from within my extension:

```
hg pull --quiet
```

Given the Mercurial API documentation, I thought it would be as simple as:

```
commands.pull(ui, repo, quiet=True)
```

Unfortunately, although this doesn't generate errors and will successfully execute the "Pull" command, the --quiet flag doesn't seem to be getting through as I still see the standard output.

All the examples only show passing non-global flags, so I'm a bit worried that this isn't possible.

What am I doing wrong?  How can I pass the --quiet flag?

Comment: This kind of question is good for mercurial-devel@selenic.com where the Mercurial developers hang out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Global options are affected through the ui object.  It allows you to control many of the things you would normally set in your (or the repository's) hgrc.  In this case, you want to set the `quiet` option in the `ui` section to True.

```
ui.setconfig('ui', 'quiet', True)
commands.pull(ui, repo)
```